# int_main()_error_'::main' must return 'int'

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Just work";

    return 0;
}
```

i dont why it is giving the error '::main' must return 'int'
I am giving the return type and value
IDE: Eclipde Mars

Comment: Your code works for me. What compiler/version?

Comment: This is even worse since the standard says if you don't `return` anything from `main` it is equivalent to `return 0;`. Your IDE is lying to you, don't listen to it.

Comment: When posting a question like this, please indicate whether you are getting compiler errors, or errors in your IDE.  A lot of times, people confuse Eclipse or Intellisense or whatever utility that is being used for the actual compiler errors.  These tools can give you false positives -- get the *real* compiler error message, if it is actually a compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your code. The return type of your `main` is `int` as it should be.

The static analyzer of eclipse cdt is not very good at parsing c++. If you don't like reading false positive error messages, then you should disable it.